# Machine learning on JSON/XML/DOM data

Tags: machine-learning, categorical-encoding, embeddings

**What's the best approach for machine learning on deeply hierarchical JSON/XML/DOM documents (not counting text nodes)?**

Say I want to recognize and generate documents similar to a training set of around 4000 documents, and assume that I can have test data with "bad" documents which I don't have yet. I have boiled my feature vector down to (`parent type`, `parent id`, `child type`, `child id` or `value`, `location of child in parent`). However, the step beyond that is my question. **Do I start doing one-hot encodings of types and ids, or do I use embeddings?**

If parents and children are the axes of my matrix, **what do I use for the values in the matrix?**  I don't have ratings, all I have is child ID/Value and child location.  **Is that what I use in the matrix to do embeddings?** (Sorry for the very general question, I'm just getting started on machine learning.)

Also, **can I do nested embeddings?** Say I want to embed words in my child values.  Also, If I use one-hot encodings or embeddings, **can I use types and ids which are not valid?** (Probably not, I would guess.)

So I'll really only be testing the structural soundness of my data.  What I want to do is generate structurally beautiful data (my documents are of a visual nature and relationships between typed data is important).  **If someone has already done this, and has a paper or open source software, please let me know.**